# Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, libraries

I am getting this error when trying to install surprise libary in python.
Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Collecting surprise
Using cached surprise-0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8 kB)
Collecting scikit-surprise
Using cached scikit-surprise-1.1.1.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\patri\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.2 in c:\users\patri\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in c:\users\patri\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\patri\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-surprise->surprise) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-surprise
Building wheel for scikit-surprise (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [75 lines of output]
C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:757: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
warnings.warn(
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\accuracy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\builtin_datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\dump.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\trainset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise_*main*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\model_selection
copying surprise\model_selection\search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\model_selection
copying surprise\model_selection\split.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\model_selection
copying surprise\model_selection\validation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\model_selection
copying surprise\model_selection_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\model_selection
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\baseline_only.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\knns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\predictions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\random_pred.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
running egg_info
writing scikit_surprise.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to scikit_surprise.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to scikit_surprise.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to scikit_surprise.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to scikit_surprise.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE.md'
writing manifest file 'scikit_surprise.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
copying surprise\similarities.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\similarities.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\co_clustering.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\optimize_baselines.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
copying surprise\prediction_algorithms\slope_one.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms
running build_ext
building 'surprise.similarities' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsurprise/similarities.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/similarities.obj
similarities.c
C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_similarities build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/similarities.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\similarities.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise\similarities.cp310-win_amd64.lib
Creando biblioteca build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise\similarities.cp310-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise\similarities.cp310-win_amd64.exp
Generando c¢digo
Generaci¢n de c¢digo finalizada
building 'surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise\prediction_algorithms
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include -IC:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsurprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.obj
matrix_factorization.c
C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.c(19777): warning C4013: '_PyGen_Send' sin definir; se supone que extern devuelve como resultado int
surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.c(19777): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' es distinto en los niveles de direccionamiento indirecto de 'int'
surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.c(19782): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' es distinto en los niveles de direccionamiento indirecto de 'int'
surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.c(19866): warning C4047: '=': 'PyObject *' es distinto en los niveles de direccionamiento indirecto de 'int'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Patri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_matrix_factorization build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.cp310-win_amd64.lib
Creando biblioteca build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.cp310-win_amd64.lib y objeto build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\surprise/prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.cp310-win_amd64.exp
matrix_factorization.obj : error LNK2001: s¡mbolo externo _PyGen_Send sin resolver
build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\surprise\prediction_algorithms\matrix_factorization.cp310-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-surprise
Running setup.py clean for scikit-surprise
Failed to build scikit-surprise
Installing collected packages: scikit-surprise, surprise
Running setup.py install for scikit-surprise ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for scikit-surprise did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [77 lines of output]

Comment: Please format the code so it is readable.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this error and was confused, I tried to read the error hint. One thing I tried and it worked was installing visual studio 2022, here's the link to install:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&channel=Release&version=VS2022&source=VSLandingPage&cid=2030&passive=false

[Install Desktop development with C++][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbp9R.png

Possible error due to library needing C++ compiler to run library, good luck and help.